# Zero points of $g$ between zero points of $f$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and $f,g: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable functions.

Furthermore, it applies that

$$f(x)g'(x) - f'(x)g(x) \neq 0 \quad \forall x \in I$$

I now need to show that between two zero points of $f$ is another zero point of $g$.

Maybe this can be proven with the mean value theorem?

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ continuously differentiable?

Comment: No, they are differentiable just once.

Comment: Ok, but is the derivative itself continuous?

Comment: The derivative is not continuous.

Comment: Hint: define a new function $h(x)=\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}$